# connection string problems in asp.net, sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, connection-string, custom-errors

I have created a database on my host using SQL server management studio and have uploaded my website, App_Code and App_Data folders. My connection string is as follows:

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="abc" 
    connectionString="Data Source=serverNane; 
    Initial Catalog=dbname;       
    Integrated Security=false;
    User ID=user;
    Password=pwd" 
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

On using my login page, i got an error as i had not added customErrors to my web.config file. After adding customErrors and a default errors page, i can not understand what error has occurred as the stack trace is not visible. Is there something wrong with my connection string?

Comment: Try using this in your web.config and see if you can get the error message `<customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>`

Comment: If you've database file under App_Data then use `AttachDbFileName` attribute.